# Problems Adding MKPolygon as an Overlay to an MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, overlay

Ey there, so as the title says, I am having a tough time adding an MKPolygon as an overlay to an MKMapView. Here is the relevant code:
*ParkingMapViewContoller.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface ParkingMapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate> {
    MKMapView *mapView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;


-(void)loadAnnotations;
-(void)showCurrentLocationButtonTapped:(id)sender;


@end
```

*ParkingMapViewController.m*

```
//...
#import "ParkingRegionOverlay.h"
//...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.title);

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:100 target:self action:@selector(showCurrentLocationButtonTapped:)];

    /*MKMapPoint points[3] = {{38.53607,-121.765793}, {38.537606,-121.768379}, {38.53487,-121.770578}};
    MKPolygon *polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:3];*/

    ParkingRegionOverlay *polygon = [[ParkingRegionOverlay alloc] initialize];
    [mapView addOverlay:polygon];

    [self loadAnnotations];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoord = { UCD_LATITUDE, UCD_LONGITUDE };
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:centerCoord zoomLevel:13 animated:NO]; //from "MKMapView+ZoomLevel.h"
}
//...

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    NSLog(@"in viewForOverlay!");

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])

    {

        MKPolygonView*    aView = [[[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon*)overlay] autorelease];

        aView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];

        aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];

        aView.lineWidth = 3;

        return aView;

    }
    return nil;
}
//...
```

*ParkingRegionOverlay.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface ParkingRegionOverlay : NSObject <MKOverlay> {
    //CLLocationCoordinate2D origin;
    MKPolygon *polygon;

    //MKMapRect rect;
}

//@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D origin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKPolygon *polygon;

//@property (nonatomic) MKMapRect rect;

-(ParkingRegionOverlay*)initialize;
-(MKMapRect)boundingMapRect;
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

*ParkingRegionOverlay.m*

```
#import "ParkingRegionOverlay.h"


@implementation ParkingRegionOverlay

//@synthesize origin;
@synthesize polygon;

//@synthesize rect;


-(ParkingRegionOverlay*) initialize {
    MKMapPoint points[3] = {{38.53607,-121.765793}, {38.537606,-121.768379}, {38.53487,-121.770578}};
    polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:3];
    polygon.title = @"Some Polygon";
    return self;
}

- (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect{
    MKMapRect bounds = MKMapRectMake(-121.770578,38.537606,-121.770578-(-121.765793),38.537606-38.53487);
    return bounds;
}

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate{
    return CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((38.537606-38.53487)/2, (-121.770578-(-121.765793))/2);
}

@end
```

You see that NSLog I stuck in the viewForOverlay: method? Well that never shows up in the console, so that function is never called. Any idea of what's wrong? Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main issue is that the code is giving the map view latitude/longitude coordinates where it expects MKMapPoints.  For an explanation of the difference, see "Understanding Map Geometry" in the [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html).  Use the MKMapPointForCoordinate function to convert from lat/long coordinates to an MKMapPoint.

The second issue is that in viewForOverlay, it is checking if overlay is of type MKPolygon.  Your overlay class ParkingRegionOverlay contains an MKPolygon object inside it but is not itself of type MKPolygon.

To fix the main issue, you need to change the initialize and boundingMapRect methods:

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        MKMapPoint points[3];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D c1 = {38.53607,-121.765793};
        points[0] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(c1);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D c2 = {38.537606,-121.768379};
        points[1] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(c2);
        CLLocationCoordinate2D c3 = {38.53487,-121.770578};
        points[2] = MKMapPointForCoordinate(c3);

        polygon = [MKPolygon polygonWithPoints:points count:3];
        polygon.title = @"Some Polygon";
    }
    return self;
}

- (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D corner1 = 
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.537606, -121.770578);
    MKMapPoint mp1 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(corner1);

    CLLocationCoordinate2D corner2 = 
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(38.53487, -121.765793);
    MKMapPoint mp2 = MKMapPointForCoordinate(corner2);

    MKMapRect bounds = 
        MKMapRectMake(mp1.x, mp1.y, (mp2.x-mp1.x), (mp2.y-mp1.y));

    return bounds;
}
```

Please notice by the way that I changed the method "initialize" to "init".  Though it wasn't preventing the polygon from showing, the way you are overriding the initialization of ParkingRegionOverlay using a method called "initialize" and not calling [super init] does not follow convention.  (Also remove "initialize" from the .h file.)

To fix the second issue, the viewForOverlay method should look like this:

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
    viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    NSLog(@"in viewForOverlay!");

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[ParkingRegionOverlay class]])
                              //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        //get the MKPolygon inside the ParkingRegionOverlay...
        MKPolygon *proPolygon = ((ParkingRegionOverlay*)overlay).polygon;

        MKPolygonView *aView = [[[MKPolygonView alloc] 
            initWithPolygon:proPolygon] autorelease];
                          //^^^^^^^^^^

        aView.fillColor = [[UIColor cyanColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
        aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        aView.lineWidth = 3;

        return aView;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Finally, change the code in viewDidLoad:

```
ParkingRegionOverlay *polygon = [[ParkingRegionOverlay alloc] init];
[mapView addOverlay:polygon];
[polygon release]; //don't forget this
```

Comment: I forgot to explain why viewDidOverlay was not being called even though the map view delegate was set (which it does need to be regardless).  The viewDidOverlay method is only called when the overlay's boundingMapRect would be visible in the current region.  Since your overlay was returning an essentially meaningless rect, it was not considered "visible" and viewDidOverlay was not getting called.

Comment: Dang man, you really know your stuff. Amazing... Thanks man! You have no idea how long I have been trying to get that to work. Oh and while I am on the topic, how would I go about making a callout pop out from the overlay when it is tapped? No need for a lengthy explanation, but if you could point me to a method or a doc that would be great. Many thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately an overlay view doesn't have a built-in callout like MKAnnotationView so more work is needed.  You can use a UIGestureRecognizer to detect the touch (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317810/how-to-capture-tap-gesture-on-mkmapview)).  Use single tap, double tap, long press--whatever works for you.  The double-tap would conflict with zoom though.  In that answer, in the handleGesture method, you can check if the touch point is in the overlay's boundingMapRect using MKMapRectContainsPoint and then popup a view.

Comment: Another easy option is to just add a regular MKPointAnnotation at the overlay's center (ie. do addOverlay and addAnnotation).  This might not look great but a lot of work is taken care of for you.

Comment: Excellent point about the distinction between MKMapPoints and lat/long coordinates. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that you forget to set your delegate
somthing like that

_mapView.delegate = self;

Comment: Nice thought, but no, I set it up through IB and the mapView is connected to ParkingMapViewController so that it is indeed mapView's delegate. I also have annotations on the map which display and function properly, which wouldn't be the case if I hadn't specified ParkingMapViewController to be the delegate of the map view.

Comment: i would suggest that set the delegate programmatically instead of in IB.

Comment: Set it programatically, but still no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you set this?:

```
yourMap.delegate=self;
```

And what's your target? 3.x or 4.x?? I think MKPolygon is available from 4.0.
You can try to add the import clause to your prefix file like:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Target is 4.1. And I tried setting my delegate just as you specified in the viewDidLoad method to no avail. I also tried your version of the import clause, but no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: try to set your MKMapView variable as 'IBOutlet MKMapView mapView;'

Comment: I already have it like so in the @property declaration, and I am sure that is not going to do anything. Nonetheless, I tried it and it didn't work.