# Point touch with zoom mapView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, mapkit

I'm trying to catch a coordinate from touch event. I can catch but when give zoom have big numbers and when I put this in a function

```
newCoord = [mapView convertPoint:location toCoordinateFromView:mapView],
```

I get wrong coordinates. What can I do?

My code:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];


NSLog(@"locationTOUCH:%f,%f", location.x,location.y);

CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord;

newCoord = [mapView convertPoint:location toCoordinateFromView:mapView];

NSLog(@"coordinate-%f,%f", newCoord.latitude,newCoord.longitude);
```

Comment: Is touch.view the same as mapView?  It's probably better to use a UIGestureRecognizer to detect touches on the map.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317810/how-to-capture-tap-gesture-on-mkmapview/4318835#4318835).  That answer doesn't mention you should also return YES in  shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer to avoid interfering with the map's gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it should be fixed by changing

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
```

to

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:mapView];
```

Comment: Ortwin is right : the views' coordinate systems are probably not the same, that's why you get wrong coordinates using one for touch detection and the other for coordinates conversion.