# MapKit Annotations Pin

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to capture Tap gesture on MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317810/how-to-capture-tap-gesture-on-mkmapview)

I'm building a `MKMapView` app, and I have one doubt! In order to drop a `Annotation Point` on the map, the user has to hold the finger on the maps for a few seconds, anyone has an idea on how to do it?? After that, he will be able to add information.

Hope anyone could help me with this!

Thanks and good year!

Comment: Are you asking how to change (i.e. reduce) the amount of time the location on the map must be touched?

Comment: Mmmmm nop. I need if anyone has an example code on how to create a pin on the map by holding the finger on the map. Thxs!

Comment: Thxs!! that was what i needed :D

Answer (score 1):

You just add a `UITapGestureRecognizer`  to your `UIView` and on the target action, add the code to drop `annotation`! An edit to @Pfitz comment ' its not "possible"- "its exact duplicate of [How to capture Tap gesture on MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317810/how-to-capture-tap-gesture-on-mkmapview)"'

Try the clear answer posted there!
Regards